# Recuperar pedidos cliente 1. ERRO de duplicação

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Meu código:

```
 SELECT   Pedido.NumPedido
    , Pedido.CdCliente
    , Cliente.Nome
    , Produto.CdProduto
    , Produto.Descricao
    , PedidoItem.Quantidade
    , PedidoItem.ValorUnitario
    , PedidoItem.ValorTotalItem

    FROM Cliente

     INNER JOIN   Pedido ON Cliente.CdCliente = Pedido.CdCliente
     INNER JOIN   PedidoItem ON Cliente.CdCliente = PedidoItem.CdCliente
     INNER JOIN   Produto ON PedidoItem.CdProduto = Produto.CdProduto

    WHERE  (PedidoItem.ValorUnitario * PedidoItem.Quantidade = PedidoItem.ValorTotalItem)  
    AND    (Cliente.Nome = 'ELETROMATIC DE GARCA LTDA')
    AND (Pedido.NumPedido = '1')

    ORDER BY ValorTotalItem ASC
```

Porém, **se eu tiro** `AND (Pedido.NumPedido = '1')` os resultados duplicam.

Ex: CodPedido 100, 101, 110 = NumPedido 1 e CodPedido 106 = NumPedido

Tirando o código fica:

CodPedido 100, 101, 110, 106 e NumPedido 8 e NumPedido 1.

Comment: tem como explicar/formatar melhor esse exemplo? ficou confuso

Comment: Olá, rLinhares. Coloquei uma imagem para melhor visualização. Eu fiz uma "gambiarra" para poder mostrar sem duplicidade, mas, está errado, pois o produto **Teste 106** tem como NumPedido o **valor 8**.

Comment: Olá, @Diego. Consegui identificar meu erro. Eu estava relacionando duas vezes o CdProduto sem necessidade. Meu erro foi nesse Inner Join ( `INNER JOIN PedidoItem ON Cliente.CdCliente = PedidoItem.CdCliente` ), onde na verdade, eu deveria relacionar com Pedido.NumPedido, para que não houvesse duplicações. Obrigada pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a tabela e a query que você mostrou, aparentemente o resultado não está duplicado porque:
Na clausula **WHERE** notei que para obter os pedidos do cliente **ELETROMATIC DE GARCA LTDA** você restringe os resultados para valores **ValorTotalItem = ValorUnitario * Quantidade**, desta forma podem existir pedidos diferentes com produtos iguais que é o seu caso. Pelo o que entendi você restringe ao **NumPedido = '1'** sendo assim a informação não esta duplica, mas sim exibindo vários pedidos que contem o mesmo produto.
Se não quiser fazer a distinção por pedido tente utilizar o **GROUP BY**.

Comment: Olá, Peterson. Consegui identificar meu erro. Eu estava relacionando duas vezes o CdProduto sem necessidade. Meu erro foi nesse Inner Join ( `INNER JOIN PedidoItem ON Cliente.CdCliente = PedidoItem.CdCliente` ), onde na verdade, eu deveria relacionar com Pedido.NumPedido, para que não houvesse duplicações. Obrigada pela atenção.